# In Java there is always at least one thread; Is this true in C++?

Tags: java, multithreading, c++11

In Java, there is always at lease one thread of execution (main()) running.  When a C++ program is executing on the operating system, does it constitute that min thread?

I ask this question because in Java `Thread.current_thread.sleep(x)` makes sense but `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{x})` is strange unless there is a thread running.

if my program has no `std::thread`s at all, is there always at least one? Also, if there are no thread running in my c++11 program, then is being able to use `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{x})` implying an answer to my question already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in C++ there is always at least one thread running. In the beginning, there is exactly one thread that does the initialization and eventually starts executing main.

Depending on how your program looks like, the main thread can start other threads. When the main function ends, the program will exit. This is different from Java where the JVM keeps running until all daemon threads are stopped.

[`std::this_thread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/) is always defined and its functions refer to the thread that is currently executing the code.